# How to correctly create a ColdFusion Builder project?

Tags: coldfusionbuilder

I am trying to run ColdFusion existing project in my local system, I am getting the error message below. Am I missing anything?

**Selected file is not in the document root of the server. If the
project is not in the document root, create a linked folder to the
document root (selecting Project Properties > ColdFusion Project)**

Comment: So this is a ColdFusion BUILDER question, not a ColdFusion one, yes? Retagging accordingly.

Comment: CFB is very "particular" about where files need to be in the project and in relation to the ColdFusion Server settings. First thing first,did you actually do what it told you to do? It's telling you to do that for a reason, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/896469?tstart=0

The bottom line:  In CFBuilder, go to the Servers view and right click on the local server running you are running against. When the initial screen comes up, check to make sure all of that is correct, then click NEXT.  On the next view ("Local Server Settings") there is a path for the Document Root.  Make sure that's correct and click Finish.

The background: I had to relocate my Apache server to a new directory with a different name. Even though I changed all of the associations in the Projects and the Workspace and the httpd.conf file for Apache, the localhost settings in CF Builder were still pointing to the old Document Root.   Once I corrected that, everything worked like a champ.